# Calculating the similarity of 2 sets of convex polygons?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, similarity

I have generated 2 sets of convex polygons from with different algorithms. Every polygon in each set is described by an array of coordinates[n_points,  xy_coords], so a square is described by an array [4,2] but a pentagon with rounded corners has [80,2], with the extra 75 points being used to describe the curvatures.

My goal is to quantify how similar the two sets of geometries are.

Can anyone recommend any methods of doing so?

So far I've come across:

- Hamming Distance
- Hausdorff distance

I would like to know what other robust measures of similarity for 2D polygons. The method ideally needs to be robust across convex polygons and and give a measure of similarity between large sets (10,000+ each).

Comment: Should this similarity measure be robust to geometric transformation like transition, rotation or scaling?

Comment: No all shapes are already centered and aligned.

Comment: As is, question has nothing to do with `python`, `numpy`, or `scikit-learn` (tags removed and replaced with `algorithm`).

Comment: You could measure a ratio of area of intersection of both sets to area of their union

Comment: Ok so from my understanding, I need to compute the IoU of both sets and then calculate the ratio of the 2. When calculating the IoU of a set, should I iteratively evaluate the IoU of each shape against all other shapes in the set?  This way seems quite computational intensive so I'm wondering if there are any other slicker methods.

Comment: Please use imgur to post pics, base64 is not supported.

Comment: Should it be sensitive to scaling?

Comment: This answer may help you determine how to approach your problem:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/253479/polygon-shape-similarity-using-qgis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that both polygons are aligned, centered and convex you could try to assess similarity by computing ratio of area a smaller polygon to area of convex hull of both polygons.

Ratio = Min(Area(A), Area(B)) / Area(ConvexHull(A, B))

The ratio will be 1 if both polygon are equal, and 0 if the differ severely like a point and a square.

Area of the polygon can be computed in O(N) time. See [Area of polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon#Area).
The convex hull can be computed in O(N log N). See [Convex Hull Computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms). It could be speed up to O(N) by merge-sorting already sorted vertices of both polygons and applying the second phase of [Graham Scan Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan).

Answer (score 2):

As I understood you look for shape similarity or shape analysis algorithms. You will find more robust methods here: https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr00/cs598b/lectures/polygonsimilarity/polygonsimilarity.pdf
and
[https://student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs763/Projects/phil.pdf](https://student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ecs763/Projects/phil.pdf)

1. Turning function;
2. Graph matching;
3. Shape signature.